# Keep UUID or IdentifierForVendor after system reset

Tags: ios, uuid

I have an app to measure to make polls, but the customer says that the people will do a factory reset just to vote again in the poll, the app doesn't let you vote unless you register, so the customer wants to preserve the UUID or identifierVendor, so that even with a factory reset the app always open with you data, I KNOW this is not how it works, i just need to justify why i can't do that, so..

Is there a way to preserve the UUID or the identifierForVendor even with device system reset?

Comment: I hope not. I don't want to buy a used iOS device and then have some app keep thinking I'm the previous owner. Very bad. What is your goal? Why do you think you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? Please [edit] your question with relevant details (don't post comments).

Comment: I made an edit, explaining the situation